# SignatureDoesNotMatch when trying to PUT an object to REST API from JSP - AWS V4 signature

Tags: java, rest, jsp, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm following these steps to create a PUT request by using V4: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sig-v4-header-based-auth.html

Just created a JSP for trying to upload a file to a S3 bucket. The issue is I always get a 403 - Forbidden. By looking at the response in detail, it says is a '**SignatureDoesNotMatch**' error, the message is '*The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method.*'
The content is actually just the string 'File contents'. These are the headers sent:

```
PUT /test.txt HTTP/1.1
Accept: /
Host: my host.s3.amazonaws.com
Date: Thu, 22 Sep 2016 04:51:52 GMT
Authorization: AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 Credential=My access ID/20160922/us-east-1/s3/aws4_request,SignedHeaders=date;host;x-amz-content-sha256;x-amz-date;x-amz-storage-class,Signature=1bqb/RTdtsOP42zs7UR4d6Id6YlNgIbO86Q1m2RuGFs=
x-amz-date: 20160922T045152Z
x-amz-content-sha256: 69423BABE8E61AAB549F347BCC8B9D77B7DCACA198FB0597BDE0B5F97F968E38
x-amz-storage-class: REDUCED_REDUNDANCY
Content-Type: text/plain
Content-Length: 13
```

The significant parts of the response body are these:

```
<CanonicalRequest>PUT
/test.txt

content-length:13
content-type:text/plain
date:Thu, 22 Sep 2016 04:51:52 GMT
host:my host.s3.amazonaws.com
x-amz-content-sha256:69423BABE8E61AAB549F347BCC8B9D77B7DCACA198FB0597BDE0B5F97F968E38
x-amz-date:20160922T045152Z
x-amz-storage-class:REDUCED_REDUNDANCY

content-length;content-type;date;host;x-amz-content-sha256;x-amz-date;x-amz-storage-class
69423BABE8E61AAB549F347BCC8B9D77B7DCACA198FB0597BDE0B5F97F968E38</CanonicalRequest>

<StringToSign>AWS4-HMAC-SHA256
20160922T045152Z
20160922/us-east-1/s3/aws4_request
17957a94c148833cd2f1132a8a4ffcfe6d2c83a71501a063f7a2ff9e7acfa1aa</StringToSign>

<SignatureProvided>1bqb/RTdtsOP42zs7UR4d6Id6YlNgIbO86Q1m2RuGFs</SignatureProvided>
```

I'm pretty sure that CanonicalRequest and StringToSing are equal on the response I get and the request I'm creating, since we are logging all this info for debugging for now. Just by comparing, I can ensure the data is exactly the same except for the '=' character at the end of the signature:

Signature at Authorization Header:

```
1bqb/RTdtsOP42zs7UR4d6Id6YlNgIbO86Q1m2RuGFs=
```

SignatureProvided at response body:

```
1bqb/RTdtsOP42zs7UR4d6Id6YlNgIbO86Q1m2RuGFs
```

I just cannot figure out why I get this SignatureDoesNotMatch error, it seems to be everything Ok (except for this '=' character, I don't know why is not being included on the SignatureProvided at the response). I have attached the code I'm using to create the request.

Is there something I'm missing? Is the first time I try to integrate with AWS. I have already spent many days trying to get it to work, it's pretty annoying :(

Thanks in advance for your help!

**EDIT:** removing the last '=' character from the signature didn't worked, same result as above.

Comment: looks like in the process of creating the signature, you are using URL encoding which is adding that extra '='.  I am not sure about the process of creating the signature.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Rahul! I'm creating a HmacSHA256 mac and signing with my AWSSecretKey. Converting back to String with DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary, not sure where URL encoding takes place there

Answer (score 0):

A quick google search told me that extra "=" is actually added by a padding factor and even quicker test case helped me in finding a way to encode without that padding.

```
@Test
public void testSign(){
    byte[] b = Base64.getDecoder().decode("1bqb/RTdtsOP42zs7UR4d6Id6YlNgIbO86Q1m2RuGFs=");
    System.out.println(Base64.getEncoder().withoutPadding().encodeToString(b));
}
```

Not suprisingly, If I remove withoutPadding(), I get = in the end, maybe you can use java.net.Base64 for encoding without padding.

Comment: Just noticed a custom base64 encoding at Amazon SDK... is not a conventional way (not any native java library): https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java/blob/8ca2018dbc4a7958c3626171e28ec467bd4a32a7/aws-java-sdk-core/src/main/java/com/amazonaws/util/Base64Codec.java
Will use their SDK for now and resume this work later, I have lost too much time with this already. Thanks again Rahul!